# Unable to get permissions even after changing permissions on a mounted directory in ubuntu 14.01

Tags: linux, postgresql, file-permissions

This is an ext4 fs and I am unable to gain permissions over the directory with the postgres user:

> mud@mud-i7-32gb:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/mud/ssd128
>
> mud@mud-i7-32gb:~$ ls -l /media/mud/ssd128/
>
> total 20
>
> drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     16384 דצמ 20 22:15 lost+found
>
> drwxr-xr-x 2 postgres postgres  4096 דצמ 21 10:45 pgdata
>
> mud@mud-i7-32gb:~$ sudo chown postgres:postgres
> /media/mud/ssd128/pgdata
>
> mud@mud-i7-32gb:~$ sudo su postgres
>
> postgres@mud-i7-32gb:/home/mud$ ls -l /media/mud/ssd128/pgdata
>
> ls: cannot access /media/mud/ssd128/pgdata: Permission denied

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What about permissions of `/media/mud` and `/media/mud/ssd128`?

Comment: is it ntfs drive?

Comment: No the FS is ext4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT - due to unclear answer

What eventually worked was:

The /media/mud/ssd128 was under root :(  - I changed it to my user which is mud instead of root

Comment: This answer seems a bit unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below method to mount disk

Find drive UUID with below command

```
blkid /dev/sdc1
```

Then Open /etc/fstab

```
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

Append below line at the end (replace UUID in below command with your UUID got from blkid command)

```
UUID=12102C02102CEB83 /media/mud/ssd128 ntfs-3g auto,users,permissions 0 0
```

Save and close the file and execute the mount command to mount disk.

```
mount -a
```

Now try to change permissions/owner. it should work for you